# Flask modeling with SQLAlchemy model inheritance

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to build a model where there is the default values then there is the user defined values. So the default values would come from the spices table. Yes the spices table would contain default data. The user would define the composite spice and make modifications as desired for a specific recipe. If you think I am structuring this wrong please provide your expertise. I feel lost on how to do this.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
   __tablename__ = 'user'
   id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=True)
   #... extra
   #... extra

class Spice(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'spices'
    code = db.Column(db.String(5), primary_key=True) # this is the id code
    name = db.Column(db.String(60))
    origin = db.Column(db.String(15))

    def __init__(self, code, name, origin):
        self.code = code
        self.name = name
        self.origin = origin

class Seasoning(Spice):
    __tablename__ = 'seasonings'
    # Note that the below item should come from Recipe. How would I do this?
    recipe_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('recipe.id'), nullable=False)


class Recipe(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'recipe'
    user = db.relationship(User)
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(60))
    description = db.Column(db.Text(), nullable=False)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    ingredient = db.relationship('Ingredient', backref='recipe', lazy='dynamic', primaryjoin="Recipe.id == Seasoning.recipe_id")
    def __init__(self, id, name, description, date):
       self.id = id
       self.name = name
       self.description = description
       self.date = date
```

in my views.py I have

```
...
  seasoning = Seasoning(code=from.code.data, name=form.name.data, origin=form.origin, 
                         recipe_id=recipe_id)
   db.session.add(seasoning)
   db.create_all()
   db.session.commit()
...
```

When I run this I do get an error when I try to commit() to seasoning. How do I resolve this?

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (raised as a result of Query-invoked
> autoflush; consider using a session.no_autoflush block if this flush
> is occurring prematurely) (sqlite3.OperationalError) table spices has
> no column named recipe_id

Answer (score 0):

You need to describe recipe_id in your spices class

> table spices has no column named recipe_id

Comment: Your explanation is lacking details on how to fix this. Can you provide some more details or a example of how to fix this?